# Webpart connection filter with Term Store metadata

Tags: sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part, managed-metadata

I'm editing a list's dispform.aspx by adding a document library and trying to filter this one.

I created a web part connection between the item ('Provide Row to') and the document library according a metadata term set.
Even by trying to map the source Term name (eg. 'MyTermField') or internal name (eg. 'MyTermField_0'), the filtered document library display no result.
Moreover, it seems not possible to define the destination mapping with the internal name.

For being sure how to create a connection, I tested with a classic choice field and I faced no problem.

Does anybody ever succeed to filter a document library with a Term set from a connection ?